# Python strip a string from config file

Tags: python, split

I have a config file that has a string which is tab separated.  I want to retrieve that string and then convert that to a nice list. But, I am seeing some interesting things that I do not see when I do it directly on iPython.

```
[myvars]
myString = "a\tb\tc\td"
.....
.....<many more variables>
```

My Python code has this:

```
param_dict = dict(config.items(myvars))
str1 = param_dict["myString"]
print str1
print str1.split()
```

And it prints out this:

```
"a\tb\tc\td"
['"a\\tb\\tc\\td"']
```

But, when I do the same thing on my python console, I get what I expect:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:38) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> "a\tb\tc\td".split()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> k = "a\tb\tc\td"
>>> k.split()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

What is going on here? Can someone help me out? I cannot change the format of the config file variables. And, I want to get the variable out and strip into a nice list.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing that `\t`is only a tab when you read it from the prompt, not when you read it from the ini-file. This is why you get double slashes in your variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The backslash is being read in here, you don't see this when you print the plain string, but do if you print the repr.

```
In [11]: myString = "a\\tb\\tc\\td"

In [12]: print(myString)
a\tb\tc\td

In [13]: print(repr(myString))
'a\\tb\\tc\\td'
```

You can use decode to convert `\\t` to `\t`:

```
In [14]: myString.decode('string_escape')
Out[14]: 'a\tb\tc\td'
```

Once they are tabs you can split on them:

```
In [15]: myString.split()
Out[15]: ['a\\tb\\tc\\td']

In [16]: myString.decode('string_escape').split()
Out[16]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 3):

That happens because in your "script" you don't have `"a\tb\tc\td"` you really have `"a\\tb\\tc\\td"` but if you make a print of `"a\\tb\\tc\\td"` it will output `"a\tb\tc\td"`

```
print myString
Output: 'a\tb\tc\td'
print repr(myString)
Output: 'a\\tb\\tc\\td'
```

You may user the function `decode` to convert the string from `'a\\tb\\tc\\td'` to `'a\tb\tc\td'` and then split or whatever you need

```
import re
myString = "a\\tb\\tc\\td"

# I prefer to use regular expressions to deal with strings:
myString = re.sub(r'\W','', myString.decode('string_escape'))
print myString
Output: 'abcd'

# Or you can use split also
myString = myString.decode('string_escape').split()
print myString
Output: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 3):

From what I see, you are mistakenly thinking that your string is tab separated in your file where it is separated by the two characters "\" and "t" which is a representation of a tab. This is shown by the representation with escaped backslashes:  "a\\tb" instead of "a\tb"

As no spacing character is present, sort doesn't know how to split the string.

You can specifiy a different delimiter in split, here the two characters \ t:

```
str1.split("\\t")
```